# Immutable.Map.deleteAll() is not a function

Tags: javascript, exception, immutable.js

Consider the following code:

```
const person = Immutable.Map({
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Maverick',
    age: 39
});

const mutated = person.deleteAll(['name', 'age']);
```

Expected result would be that `mutated` now is a new instance of Map with the keys `name` and `age` deleted. However, throws an exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: person.deleteAll is not a function

When inspecting the available methods of `Immutable.Map` prototype, there is no `deleteAll` nor `removeAll` methods. Have they been removed?

The method is listed in the official ImmutableJS documentation, but it is not available. What would be a native Immutable alternative in this case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's only been added on the latest version (`ver. 4 RC1 & RC2`). I looked over the `src` code and it's not found in the `3.8.1`. Unless you want to use `4.0.0-rc.2`, there's no other way to use that method yet.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, `deleteAll` is only in the release candidate.  You can get the same result with ...

```
const mutated = ['name', 'age'].reduce((map, key) => map.delete(key), person);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should be using deleteIn?

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/deleteIn

```
person.deleteIn(['name', 'age']);
```

Comment: `deleteIn`, as its similar `xxxIn` methods, will delete the end entry by the path you provide. Your example would work had I had: `const person = Immutable.Map({ name: { age: 39 } });`