# Calling deleteAll on a valid Map returns a TypeError

Tags: immutable.js

I'm running into a weird problem that may just be due to ignorance with regards to ImmutableJS on my part.

Here's the code:

```
const myMap = Immutable.fromJS({
    a: {
        b: 1,
        c: 2
    }
});

console.log(Immutable.Map.isMap(myMap)); //true
console.log(Immutable.Map.isMap(myMap.get('a'))); //true

myMap.map(item => {
    console.log(Immutable.Map.isMap(item)); //true
    item.deleteAll(['b']); //Causes "Uncaught TypeError: item.deleteAll 
        is not a function"
});
```

I'm baffled as to what's going on. If I had called `item.get('b')` instead of `item.deleteAll(['b'])` it works fine.

Edit:  Link to CodePen example above: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybPaPo?editors=0011

Comment: What's the `type` of `item`?

Comment: It's a Map, at least from Immutable's perspective (`Immutable.Map.isMap(item) === true`)

Comment: Whoops sorry, missed that. Don't know Immutable.js, but unless `fromJS` recursively makes everything inside the object also immutable, `item` will just be a normal JS object, which doesn't have that method.

Comment: Also potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996368/immutable-map-deleteall-is-not-a-function

Comment: Humour me, write `console.log(type(item))`. `isMap` may be checking for it to be a map, but not necessarily an immutable one. In that case, `Immutable.Map.isMap({})` would be true.

Comment: Aha! You nailed it - as indicated in the question you linked above, Immutable.Map.deleteAll isn't available in 3.8.1, which is the version I'm using. Great catch, and thanks!

Comment: Np. Note the other thing though, unless `fromJS` is recursive, `item` still won't have that method.

Comment: fromJS is indeed recursive. Thanks again!

Comment: Ahh, and ok, np. Voting to close as a duplicate.