# How to update Immutable js new version using command prompt..?

Tags: windows, reactjs, command-line, redux, immutable.js

**Environment:** Windows

I am working in react [immutable js](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) with the function `deleteAll()` which shows error as `deleteAll is not a function` and also for `removeAll()`.

[deleteAll()](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/deleteAll) function listed in [OrderedMap](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap) official documentation.

Checked that `deleteAll()` is available only in version `4.0.0-rc.2` in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996368/immutable-map-deleteall-is-not-a-function).

Noticed that the file => `node_modules\immutable\package.json`, showing version as `"version": "3.8.2"` in my project.

Using the below code in my reducer also shows error, due to the old version `3.8.2`:

```
const {OrderedMap } = require('immutable@4.0.0-rc.9');
```

Also tried again the command `npm install immutable`, same version(`3.8.2`) persist.

What is the windows command to update immutable js to new version `4.0.0-rc.2`..?

Comment: Change the version in `package.json` to the version you want, delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.

Comment: If i delete, `node_modules` folder, the file which is changed version in `package.json` will also gets delete right..?

Comment: If you delete `node_modules`, all the packages that you have installed last time you ran `npm install` will get deleted. Next time you run the install, the edited `package.json` will take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually:

Change the version in `package.json` to the version you want, delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.

Via CLI:

`npm install immutable@4.0.0-rc.2`

Comment: If i delete `node_modules` folder, all other packages also gets delete.? Is there any way or can i delete only `immutable` folder inside  `node_modules` folder..?

Comment: All the packages will get deleted but your `package.json` will stay intact, deleting `node_modules` and running a clean install is a common practice. Everything will come back once you run `npm install` again.

Comment: I will try the way u suggested to me.. Help for my future doubts regarding to 
 this issue. Thanks..

Comment: Yes yes sure.. Takes 3 minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: Hii.. I directly used the command without delete any folder. My immutable js version updated successfully in `package.json`

Comment: That's the best way to do it, enjoy